# Kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to write a common library using [Kotin multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-dsl-reference.html) that can be used on `android` and on `ios`.
This library will have dependencies for each platform, for eg: on `android` I want to add [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) as a dependency and on `ios` I want to add [swiftsoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

For `android` adding java libraries as dependencies is rather easy, but for `ios` I could not find a way.

The question is: how can I add a `swift` library as a dependency to this project for `ios`?

or can somebody point me to a working project as an example? I could not find anything on the internet that could solve my issue.

```
build.gradle.kts :

import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

    val serializationVersion = "0.20.0"
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"

    plugins {
        kotlin("multiplatform") version kotlinVersion
        kotlin("plugin.serialization") version kotlinVersion
    }

    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlinVersion")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    kotlin {
        //select iOS target platform depending on the Xcode environment variables
        val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
                if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
                    ::iosArm64
                else
                    ::iosX64

        iOSTarget("ios") {
            binaries {
                framework {
                    baseName = "SharedCode"
                }
            }
        }

        jvm("android")

        sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serializationVersion")
        }

        sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
            implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serializationVersion")
        }

        sourceSets["iosMain"].dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serializationVersion")
        }

    }

    val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
        group = "build"

        //selecting the right configuration for the iOS framework depending on the Xcode environment variables
        val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
        val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios").binaries.getFramework(mode)

        inputs.property("mode", mode)
        dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

        val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
        from({ framework.outputDirectory })
        into(targetDir)

        doLast {
            val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
            gradlew.writeText("#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n")
            gradlew.setExecutable(true)
        }
    }

    tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Swift dependencies in Kotlin unless they are compatible with Objective-C. If you want to talk to them directly, you'll need to point to them with cinterop. Alternatively, you can create interfaces in Kotlin, or take lambdas, that are implemented by Swift code, and avoid cinterop.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html

We pass in a lot of implementations in one of our example apps: https://github.com/touchlab/DroidconKotlin/blob/master/iosApp/iosApp/app/AppDelegate.swift#L33